# Looking for a regular expression used on variable string

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that can vary slightly:

```
str1 = "[X] text [Y] abc123"
str1 = "(X ) text [y ]  abc123"
str1 = "(x) text (Y)        abc123"
str1 = "(X ) text   (Y)  abc123"
str1 = "(X ) text [Y ]  abc123"
str1 = "[X]   text333 [y]  abc123222"
```

so basically X and Y are static and they can either be between `()` or `[]`. My problem is, that there can be some white spaces as well. X and Y with bracket can be assumed as delimiter to capture group 1. I am currently asking myself how to parse "text" and "abc123" in the most reliable way. How would you do it? "text" and "abc123" are variable strings. I want to use them further

Comment: Are you trying to capture `test` and `abc123` patterns in those strings?

Comment: `\s*(\[|\()\s*[xXyY]\s*(\]|\))\s*` should work, but for some reason produces garbage when feeded into `re.split`

Comment: What specifically is text and abc123.

Comment: I want to extract the first string (in this example `text` but it can be any text!) as well as the second (in the example `abc123` but it can be any text!) to use them further. So I just want to use [X] and [Y] as delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```python
import re

str1 = "( X ) text [Y] abc 123 xyz"

m = re.match( r'^[\(\[][xX ]+[\]\)]\s*(\S*)\s*[\(\[][yY ]+[\]\)]\s*(.*)$', str1)

if m:
   str1text = m.group(1)
   str1moretext = m.group(2)
   print str1text
   print str1moretext
else:
   print "No match!!"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
chars='[]()'
x,text,y,abc123 = ''.join([x for x in str1 if x not in chars]).split()
print(x,text,y,abc123)
```

Comment: I think I didn't express my self good enough. I am trying to extract two variable strings (text and abc123 in the example above). [x] and [y] are just delimiters

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
[\[)]X[\])]\s*(.+?)\s*[\[(]Y[\])]\s*(.+)
```

`text` will be in group 1 and `abc123` in group 2

**Explanation:**

```
[\[)]   : character class `[` or `(`
X       : whatever X stands for
[\])]   : character class `]` or `)`
\s*     : 0 or more space character
(.+?)   : 1 or more any character non greedy, captured in group 1
\s*     : 0 or more space character
[\[(]   : character class `[` or `(`
Y       : whatever X stands for
[\])]   : character class `]` or `)`
\s*     : 0 or more space character
(.+)    : 1 or more any character, captured in group 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex you want could be `r'(?i)\s*(?:\[\s*(?:X|Y)\s*\]|\(\s*(?:X|Y)\s*\))\s*'`
This assumes that `[]` or `()` pairs must match, and that (as you show in your example) X and Y can be either upper or lower case (or mixed case, if `X` or `Y` is a longer token).  It does not require that `[X]` preceed `[Y]`.

If you use this regex to split any of your `str1` values, you'll get an array of 3 elements (`['', 'text', 'abc123']`).

```
strs = [ "[X] text [Y] abc123",
         "(X ) text [y ]  abc123",
         "(x) text (Y)        abc123",
         "(X ) text   (Y)  abc123",
         "(X ) text [Y ]  abc123",
         "[X]   text333 [y]  abc123222", ]

for s in strs:
    print(re.split(r'(?i)\s*(?:\[\s*(?:X|Y)\s*\]|\(\s*(?:X|Y)\s*\))\s*', s))
```

prints

```
['', 'text', 'abc123']
['', 'text', 'abc123']
['', 'text', 'abc123']
['', 'text', 'abc123']
['', 'text', 'abc123']
['', 'text333', 'abc123222']
```